# Redirect specific author posts to another url

Tags: functions, filters, redirect

```
if (is_author('admin')){
    add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_redirect_posts_to_new_page');
    function wpse_redirect_posts_to_new_page() {
        // if this is not a single post or not of type post, do nothing
        if ( ! is_single() || get_post_type() != 'post')
            return;

        $url = parse_url(get_the_permalink());
        $newdomain = 'https://www.example.com';
        wp_redirect($newdomain . $url['path']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

currently, it's redirecting all users post to new url

Answer (score 0):

First of all... `[is_author][1]` doesn't check if given user is author of current post. Straight from Codex:

> This Conditional Tag checks if an Author archive page is being
>   displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE
>   or FALSE.

So it won't help you.

Another problem with your code is that you perform this check to early. If this code is pasted in `functions.php`, then the if condition will be checked before query is parsed.

So how should it really look like? Something like this:

```
function wpse_redirect_posts_to_new_page() {
    // if this is not a single post or not of type post, do nothing
    if ( ! is_single() || 'post' != get_post_type() ) {
        return;
    }

    $post = get_queried_object();  // it's single, so this will be a post
    if ( AUTHOR_ID != $post->post_author ) { // change AUTHOR_ID to real ID of the author
        return;
    }

    $url = parse_url(get_the_permalink());
    $newdomain = 'https://www.example.com';
    wp_redirect($newdomain . $url['path']);
    exit;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_redirect_posts_to_new_page');
```

Comment: where to declare the author id?

Comment: @charchit wherever you want. You can even replace this constant with number.

Comment: it's not working for me, can you test it? if you can share the specific code it 'll be helpful.thanks